# Issue with script initialization in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ when using NFS storage in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

I encountered a problem while initializing scripts in the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ directory when running a PostgreSQL container in Kubernetes using NFS storage. While debugging the docker-entrypoint.sh script, I noticed that the condition if [ -z "$DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS" ]; then is not being met, leading to the skipping of script initialization.

The docker-entrypoint.sh script contains the following code snippet:

```
if [ -s "$PGDATA/PG_VERSION" ]; then
    DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS='true'
fi
```

I found that the value of the DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS variable is set to true due to the existence of the $PGDATA/PG_VERSION file. In my case, the PGDATA variable is set to /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata.

The volume mount in my YAML file looks like this:

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: db-nfs-pvc
    mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    subPath: pgdata
```

To create the PersistentVolumeClaim, I'm using the following YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: db-nfs-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: nfs-csi
```

Additionally, I have defined a StorageClass for NFS storage:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: nfs-csi
provisioner: nfs.csi.k8s.io
parameters:
  server: 192.168.0.10
  share: /share
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
mountOptions:
  - nfsvers=4.1
```

My initialization scripts in the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ directory are not being executed due to this issue. How can I resolve this problem and ensure that the scripts run during container startup? I would appreciate any tips or recommendations to fix this situation. Thank you!

Comment: That sounds like there's already an initialized database in that storage location?  The Docker container init scripts don't run if the database already exists.